# GCP BigQuery how to query only values from all qualifiers

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm new to BigTable and how it structures data, but I recently connected it to BigQuery to run some tests and I noticed that the data looks something like this:

```
family.qualifier_name.cell.value
```

In my table I only have 1 family and I want to get all the "value" data from each qualifier_name in that family. I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
SELECT family.*.cell.value FROM [my-project:my-instance.my-table] WHERE rowkey="something"
```

But of course this doesn't work. I basically just want the values from all of the qualifiers. I also tried doing this:

```
SELECT family.q0.cell.value, family.q1.cell.value, family.q2.cell.value [...] FROM [my-project:my-instance.my-table] WHERE rowkey="something"
```

But because the values are nested within the qualifier, I get this error:

```
Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you show an example of how the data looks (e.g. by selecting "JSON" under "Preview" for the table)? If you're just getting started, please stick with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql), since it has better handling of repeated fields.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid "Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time" -> switch to Standard SQL.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql

To get results in a table similar as the one described:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_dim.user_properties, user_dim.app_info, user_dim.geo_info
FROM `sara-bigquery.fb_analytics_android.app_events_20160607`
WHERE user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros  = 146356300475300038
LIMIT 1000
```